# ¿Como puedo autollenar 2 inputs dependiendo de lo que seleccione en un dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql, entrada, autocompletar, dropdownlist

Tengo un dropdwon el cual muestra como opciones los campos de una tabla en mysql, hasta aqui todo bien. También tengo 2 inputs los cuales quiero que se llenen según lo que se elija en el dropdown. La información con la que quiero que se llenen estos inputs son datos del mismo registro que se haya seleccionado en el dropdown.

La tabla se llama oferentes en mysql, en el dropdown se muestra el id de cada oferente y en un input quiero se muestre el nombre y en el otro input la nacionalidad. Todo esto dependiendo del id que seleccione.

**Este es el php en el que se muestran el dropdown y los inputs:**

```html
$query = 'SELECT * FROM oferentes';

     $result = $mysqli->query($query);

     ?>
     <div class="row ">
       <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
       <p style="text-align:left;"> ID del Oferente:</p>
       <select  id="IDOferente" class="browser-default col s12 m10 l10" name="IDOferente" onchange="pruebita2()">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el ID del Oferente</option>
         <?php
         while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
         {
             ?>


          <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente'] ?> "
                  data-nombre="<?php echo $row['NombreOferente'] ?>"
                  data-nacionalidad="<?php echo $row['Nacionalidad'] ?>">
            <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente']; ?>

          </option>

          <?php
      }
      ?>
       </select>
       </div>
     </div>
     
     
     
     <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">folder_shared</i>
      <input id="nombre"  type="text" name="nombre" class="validate" required>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre Oferente</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
      <input id="nacionalidad"  type="text" name="nacionalidad" class="validate" required>
      <label for="nacionalidad">Nacionalidad</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
  <select class="browser-default" type="hidden" id="TipoOferente" name="TipoOferente" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el tipo de Oferente</option>
    <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
    <option value="Consorcio">Consorcio</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>


<script >

window.onload = function(){

    var select = document.getElementById("IDOferente");

    select.addEvenListener("change", function(){
        var nombre = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.nombre;
        var nacionalidad = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.nacionalidad;

        document.getElementById("nombre").value = nombre;
        document.getElementById("nacionalidad").value = nacionalidad;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var select = document.getElementById("IDOferente");

    select.addEvenListener("change", function(){
        var nombre = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.nombre; 
        var nacionalidad = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.nacionalidad;

        document.getElementById("nombre").value = nombre;
        document.getElementById("nacionalidad").value = nacionalidad;
    }
}
```

Y ahora cuando cargas la página debes añadir con php en tu option:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM oferentes';

     $result = $mysqli->query($query);

     ?>
     <div class="row ">
       <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
       <p style="text-align:left;"> ID del Oferente:</p>
       <select  id="IDOferente" class="browser-default col s12 m10 l10" name="IDOferente" onchange="pruebita2()">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el ID del Oferente</option>
         <?php
         while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
         {
             ?>


          <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente'] ?> " 
                  data-nombre="<?php echo $row['nombre_Oferente'] ?>"
                  data-nacionalidad="<?php echo $row['nacionalidad_Oferente'] ?>">
            <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente']; ?>

          </option>

          <?php
      }
      ?>
       </select>
       </div>
     </div>


     <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">folder_shared</i>
      <input id="nombre"  type="text" name="nombre" class="validate" required>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre Oferente</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
      <input id="nacionalidad"  type="text" name="nacionalidad" class="validate" required>
      <label for="nacionalidad">Nacionalidad</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ahroa cada vez que se cambie el select, JavaScript cogerá el valor de los atributos personalizados del option y los pondrá en los input correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuestaamigo, intente el código pero por algún motivo no muestra nada en los inputs. Cambie ciertas cosas como en el data-nombre en la tabla le el campo de NombreOferente e igual data-nacionalidad en la tabla leería Nacionalidad y no nacionalidad_oferente. Crei que ese seria el problema pero aún no muestran nada los inputs.

Comment: la consola de JavaScript te muestra algún error? Creo que esta mal la linea JavaScript getAttibute, hay que cambiarla por getAttributem le falta una R y quizas es lo que esta parando la ejecución javascript, ademas de un error al seleccionar inputs y atributos, te lo edito para que pruebes y me dices

Comment: no amigo, el php corre sin problemas pero no muestra nada en los inputs.

Comment: no me refiero a php, si no a la consola javascript, de todas formas creo que detecte todos los fallos, vuelve a probar y me dices que tal

Comment: aunque recuerda cambiar como cambiastes antes los nombres de las propiedades php por tus nombres en base de datos, $row['tuNombreEnBD']

Comment: perdón mi error, la consola igual no muestra errores. Aún con los cambios no funciona amigo. Lo que yo cambie fue **nombre_oferente** por NombreOferente y **nacionalidad_oferente** por Nacionalidad ya que asi estan los campos en la tabla pero parece que ese no es el problema ya que aún no aparecen los datos en los inputs.

Comment: Copia y pega el código que estas probando, a ver que se puede hacer

Comment: Perdón, fallo mio, te edite la respuesta, loas atributos personalizados que html se recogen con javascript con elemento.dataset.nombre, elemento.dataset.nacionalidad, te lo cambié de nuevo, aver si así...

Comment: Aún nada amigo, edite el código que publiqué para que observes que relice los cambios tal cual me indicabas. Y le veo lógica a todo lo que me dices pero los inputs aún no muestran nada.

Comment: tienes otro window.onload en otro sitio de la página? prueba a poner mi javascript abajo, tal y como se muestra en tu codigo copiado y quitale el  window.onload = function(){ ...codigo... }, acuerdate de quitar la llave de cierre tambien

Comment: Hola, acabo de ver la respuesta, esta muy interesante, tal vez deberías evitar usar las lineas `window.onload = function(){` y `select.addEvenListener("change", function(){` y utilizar una función con `onchange`, vi que funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @the-breaker , si, pero aun así no debería lanzar ningún problema y por limpieza según la W3S se debería utilizar así, aunque a unas malas si quitando el window.onload = function(){} no funciona estaría bien que lo probase como dices,

Comment: @the-breaker probé como dijiste y funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: @montes18295 muchas gracias por el código y por tomarte el tiempo de responder amigo, de nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, a programar!