# Cargar otros campos Al seleccionar registro

Tags: php

necesito ayuda al momento de dar en el select y seleccionar el registro deseo que los campos que estan vacios se rellenen con informacion de este, este es mi codigo:

```
                        <form role="form" method="post" action="../../../../Controlador/reporteBeteitivaController.php?action=crear">

                                <div class="row ">
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 center-page" style="width: 83%">


                                        <div class="row ">

                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Trabajador"><strong>Trabajador</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-verde btn-bordered" id="Trabajador" name="Trabajador" required >
                                                    <?php echo trabajadorController::selectTrabajadorBeteitiva(true, "idTrabajador", "idTrabajador", "form-control"); ?>

                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Labor"><strong>Labor Minera</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Labor" class="form-control" disabled="" >
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <br>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Nombre"><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Nombre" class="form-control" disabled="" >
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Centro"><strong>Centro Costo</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Centro" class="form-control" disabled="" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <br>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Frente"><strong>Frente Trabajo</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Frente" class="form-control" disabled="" >
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="Fecha"><strong>Fecha</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"  name="Fecha" id="datepicker-autoclose">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-success b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar text-white"></i></span>
                                                </div><!-- input-group -->
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group text-center">

                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-gris font-15" style="border-radius: 5px">
                                                <strong>Cancelar</strong>
                                            </button>



                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-verde  font-15" value="validate"   style= "border-radius: 5px">
                                                <strong>Registrar</strong>
                                            </button>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                            </form>
```

Lo que deseo es que al momento de seleccionar el valor del select con el `id="Trabajador"` me carge en los `input` Labor, Nombre, Centro, los cuales son campos del registro "Trabajador".

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías dar mas detalles del problema? Edita la pregunta para agregar mas información.

Comment: Listo amigo, perdón por no hacerme ententer :D

Comment: ya veo el problema, hay una respuesta muy buena que te puede ayudar en esta pregunta [¿Como puedo autollenar 2 inputs dependiendo de lo que seleccione en un dropdown?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165040)

Comment: Si amigo pero en ese no es muy claro que se diga